# What is the inverse operation to this pickle command?

Tags: python, pickle

when trying to apply some code i found on the internet i ran into a dataset that was pickled. Now to insert my own dataset into that i need to reverse the pickling myself. The piece of code that reads the pickle is:

```
import cPickle, gzip, numpy

# Load the dataset
f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

And i want to write the pickle myself now:

```
with open(outfile) as f:
    train_set = allfiles[:len(allfiles)/3] 
    valid_set = allfiles[len(allfiles)/3:(len(allfiles)/3)*2] 
    test_set  = allfiles[(len(allfiles)/3)*2:]

    cPickle.dump((train_set,valid_set,test_set), outfile,0)
```

However i get :

```
 TypeError: argument must have 'write' attribute
```

What could be my problem? How would a good pickling code look like?

Comment: Always provide a full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the *file object*, not the filename:

```
cPickle.dump((train_set,valid_set,test_set), f, 0)
```

However, your input was GZIP-compressed as well:

```
with gzip.open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    # ...
    cPickle.dump((train_set,valid_set,test_set), f, 0)
```

Note that your own code forgot to state the correct mode for the opened file object as well; `open(outfile)` without arguments opens the file in read-modus, and writes would fail with an `IOError: File not open for writing` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
cPickle.dump((train_set,valid_set,test_set), outfile,0)
```

`outfile` is just a file name. You should use:

```
cPickle.dump((train_set,valid_set,test_set), f,0)
```